# How to register dependencies based on the class they are required from(using built-in IOC-container in ASP CORE)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I am trying to register different implementations of one interface and depending on the classes, which are using these implementations, certain one to be passed.

```
public interface ITest { }
public class Test1 : ITest { } 
public class Test2 : ITest { }

public class DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest1
{
    private ITest test;

    public DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest1(ITest test)
    {
        this.test = test;
    }
}

public class DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest2
{
    private ITest test;

    public DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest2(ITest test)
    {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

Current solution:

```
services.AddTransient(x=>new DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest1(new Test1()));
services.AddTransient(x=>new DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest2(new Test2()));
```

This works well unless you have a classes with lots of dependencies, where "x.GetRequiredService" should be called for every dependency in the constructor.

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
services.AddTransient<ITest, Test1>
    (/*If ITest is required by DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest1*/);
services.AddTransient<ITest, Test2>
    (/*If ITest is required by DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest2*/);
```

Is there any other way I have missed for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works well unless you have a classes with lots of dependencies, where "x.GetRequiredService" should be called for every dependency in the constructor.

This is a good use-case for [`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=aspnetcore-3.0). Here's an example:

```
services.AddTransient(sp =>
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest1>(sp, new Test1()));
```

`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>` creates an instance of the type specified (`DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest1` in this example) using a combination of the DI container and any additional parameters you pass. The first argument passed in is the `IServiceProvider` and any additional parameters are used to provide explicit values by type.

In the example shown, `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` will:

- Look for a suitable constructor for `DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest1` and analyse its parameters.
- Match anything you provide as additional parameters by assignable type against constructor parameters. We provide an instance of `Test1` which is assignable to `ITest`, so that is used in the next step.
- Create an instance of `DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest1` by matching parameters with the values you provided. For anything that you didn't provide, it attempts to resolve the values from the DI container using `GetService`.

This affords you the convenience of not having to worry about connecting all the DI-provided dependencies for `DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest1` while still allowing you to specify those you *do* care about.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo like below:

1.Interface:

```
public interface ITest {
    string play();
}
```

2.implement class:

```
public class Test1 : ITest
{
    public string play()
    {
        return "111";
    }
}
public class Test2 : ITest
{
    public string play()
    {
        return "222";
    }
}
```

3.test class:

```
public class DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest1
{
    private IEnumerable<ITest> test;

    public DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest1(IEnumerable<ITest> test)
    {
        this.test = test;
    }  
    public string Get()
    {
        var flag = test.FirstOrDefault(h => h.GetType().Name == "Test1");
        var value = flag?.play();
        return value;
    }
}
public class DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest2
{
    private IEnumerable<ITest> test;

    public DoSmthWhichCurrentlyNeedsTest2(IEnumerable<ITest> test)
    {
        this.test = test;
    }
    public string Get() 
    {
        var flag = test.FirstOrDefault(h => h.GetType().Name == "Test2");
        var value = flag?.play();
        return value;
    }
}
```

4.Startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<ITest, Test1>();
services.AddTransient<ITest, Test2>();
```

5.Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi. Your solution is working, but passing all implementations to the constructor and choosing one of them after that is not better than explicitly resolving them in the "startup.cs" in the way I've already shown. What I am looking for is a build-in way in the IOC-container of ASP CORE. Unfortunately, at that moment I can't find solution. 
Тhanks for the effort though.